# How to import and export messages to queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

We are developing a system which uses rabbitMQ for sending and receiving data between its clients and servers.
The internet connection may sometimes be lost.

1- Can all the messages in the queue be exported to a file ? And somehow be imported to the client using this file?

2- In a different scenario, a client wants to send some messages to the queue but it has no internet connection! So we want to export all the message from client and make a file and somehow send it to the server (eg. transfer it to another location which has internet), Is this possible to import this file to the queue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same questions as I wanted to replay messages for testing / load testing purposes.

I made RabbitDump, a `dotnet tool`, to do this. It allows you to do all possible transfers from AMQP to and from Zip (bunch of messages). Examples: `AMQP => ZIP`, `AMQP => AMQP`, `ZIP => AMQP` and `ZIP => ZIP` (because why not ..).

The [tool can be found here](https://github.com/LordMike/MBW.Tools.RabbitDump). It's installable as a `dotnet tool`, using `dotnet tool install --global MBW.Tools.RabbitDump`.

Comment: You're a lifesaver 

Comment: the tool will only work on dotnet core 6 (unfortunately on our old servers we have only .net framework)

Answer (score 1):

This [tool](https://github.com/jecnua/rabbitmq-export-to-local) will be useful to export messages from the remote queue and push them on a local RabbitMQ.

https://github.com/jecnua/rabbitmq-export-to-local

Comment: the client can not install the docker, any other suggestions?

Comment: this is just a wrapper around https://github.com/dubek/rabbitmq-dump-queue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can import/export messages using QueueExplorer.
Disclaimers: I'm the author, it's a commercial tool, and for now on Linux it runs under Wine.

https://www.cogin.com/QueueExplorer/rabbitmq/