# Is it possible export rabbitmq messages to local file(like .txt file)?

Tags: rabbitmq

There are 15302 events waiting for 2-3 years in a queue that has no consumer as an error queue in windows prod rabbitmq.Instead of writing the consumer listening to these events, we want to import them into txt and quickly import them.

Is it possible export rabbitmq messages to local file(like .txt file)?

I could not find anything about my request.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55768867/5249021) useful. It refers to a tool which is available at [github](https://github.com/LordMike/MBW.Tools.RabbitDump).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tool with a nice GUI: https://www.cogin.com/mq/. It provides the export/import feature.

Comment: thanks muhammed but this tool will install to our production system.Actually i saw this method but I could not make sure is it safe.